# Is there any way to set multiple LIKE options inside where clause in cakephp 3

Tags: sql, cakephp-3.0

I want to retrieve all rows matched on multiple partial prase against with a column. My situation can be explained as following raw sql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE %abc% 
   OR COLUMN1 LIKE %bcd% 
   OR COLUMN1 LIKE %def%;
```

Here, abc, bcd, def are array elements. i.e: `array('abc','bcd','def')`. Is there any way to write code passing this array to form the above raw sql using cakephp 3?

N.B: I am using mysql as DBMS.

Comment: cant you chain `OrWhere`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you can use Collection to create a proper array, but I think a foreach loop will do the job in the same amount of code. So here is my solution supposing `$query` stores your Query object

```
$a = ['abc','bcd','def'];
foreach($a as $value)
{
    $or[] = function ($exp, $q) use ($value) {
        return $exp->like('column1', '%'.$value.'%');
    };
}
$query->where(['or' => $or]);
```

you could also use `orWhere()` but I see it will be deprecated in 3.6

Comment: Thanks for your time. suppose, I have an array like $arr= array('abc'); how to modify your answer to replace hard code %abc% with my $arr variable?

Comment: sorry, I missed the array part of you question, see my new answer